# Android Studio 2.3 Error. Not rendering the layout in the Design tab

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-2.3

I Have this error in the latest stable version of Android Studio (2.3.1) i have it occur yesterday i thought it can be fixed by restarting the application then today when i checked, after several restart. It still render an empty

I Tried reporting it to google and there is an error in the Report, i dont know if its relevant so im just going to post the error i get.

I have no gradle error but when i see the event log there is a nullpoineterexception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.handlers.constraint.ConstraintUtilities.updateWidgetFromComponent(ConstraintUtilities.java:1323)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.handlers.constraint.ConstraintModel.updateSolverWidgetFromComponent(ConstraintModel.java:821)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.handlers.constraint.ConstraintModel.updateSolverWidgetFromComponent(ConstraintModel.java:823)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.handlers.constraint.ConstraintModel.updateNlModel(ConstraintModel.java:591)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.handlers.constraint.ConstraintModel.lambda$modelChanged$1(ConstraintModel.java:235)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$6.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:291)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:326)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:310)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

[image]

Well i dont know if it helps solve the mystery but i downloaded plugins in android studio that night before it occur

Comment: I'm getting the same stack trace but the behavior is different, in my case it renders partially ok but there are some weird things happening, like the margins not showing up in the constraints properties view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
In your android studio,
Go to **File**>**Invalidate caches and restart**
Confirm your choice if it asks for it. 
Then see if it is working or not.

Comment: I did this already but to reassure this im going to do it again. thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Constraint Layout for Android in the support Repository.

**Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools** [constraintLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBD1d.png)

Since you are using ConstraintLayout, this repository should be installed

Find out more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

Comment: Yes i have installed that already, its fine the other day. im developing it for 1 week and its the first time it occured. i dont know what to do :(

Comment: Did you try changing the sdk version ?